# Why do Toasts and Dialogs not work from ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2?

Tags: android, testing

For some reason, Toast.makeText().show() and dialog.show() calls do nothing when called from test methods in an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 class.

Does anyone know why or how to fix this?

Example:

```
public class MyTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {

    public MyTest(String name)
    {
        super("com.mypackage.activities", MyActivity.class);
        setName(name);
    }

    public exampleTest()
    {
        //This works to show that the test class is running correctly
        TouchUtils.drag(this, 200.0F, 200.0F, 300.0F, 300.0F, 5);

        //The following line does nothing
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "toast message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Sleep to make sure we can see the message
        SystemClock.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need perform your code on Application's UI thread:

```
MyActivity myActivity = getActivity();

// create a toast on application's ui thread.
// you can also use getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync() here.
myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(myActivity, "toast message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});

// wait a second to see the effect.
try {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using Thread.sleep is not the done thing. In your tests you should be using `Instrumentation.runOnMainSync` - "Execute a call on the application's main thread, blocking until it is complete."